# duplicate form elements on jquery form ajax submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin, jqueryform

I am dynamically adding a SELECT element to a form, then submitting using JQuery Form Plugin for an ajax form submit. I want to (1) add the SELECT to the form, (2) place the SELECT inside a DIV and (3) submit the form using an ajax call properly. I can't seem to do all three!

```
<form name="mainForm" id="mainForm" method="POST" action="fellowRight.php">
  ...various working form elements

<div class="field_wrapper">
  </div>

  </form>
```

The code above is a snippet of a form in use. I then add some additional select elements dynamically as per below

```
 $(addFormElementButton).click(function(){ 
     var fieldHTML = '<select required name="ABC" ><option value="LT">Left</option><option selected value="RT">Right</option></select>';          
     $('.field_wrapper'); .append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
     $('select[name=ABC]').appendTo('#mainForm');
  }
```

The problem is that elements "appendto" the form, not the div "`.field_wrapper`" as intented (and therefore appear outside of the intended DIV). I can get it to format correctly if I omit the appendTo but then the select is no longer linked to the form.

If I omit the AppendTo code and instead I add a `form="mainForm"` call in the `<select>` element, it formats correctly and submits correctly. HOWEVER, then I get duplication of this specific SELECT element in my form data submitted via JQUERY FORM (.ajaxForm).

Is there a way to link the SELECT element to the form without using `appendTo` or `form=` or should I just forget about using Jquery Form

Comment: `$('.field_wrapper'); .append(fieldHTML);` I think this is not valid syntax

Comment: just typed wrong here, syntax is correct in true code, thx

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the `select` inside `.field_wrapper`, it's already inside the form.

You may also want to cancel the click event on `addFormElementButton`, because if it's a `button` it might be submitting the form automatically.

```
$(addFormElementButton).click(function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
     var fieldHTML = '<select required name="ABC" ><option value="LT">Left</option><option selected value="RT">Right</option></select>';          
     $('.field_wrapper').append(fieldHTML);  //<-there was a typo here
});
```

Comment: typo was correct in true code. unfortunately, if i dont either append to form OR add name='mainform', despite being inside the form and /form tags, the data doesnt POST

Comment: Well, then you'll have to post how you're sendig the form. Post tha ajax call part.